# Snowsql join or casting issue

Tags: join, casting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

so I'm having a join issue with Snowsql query. I have 3 seperate styles in query below AND I cannot get the AUDIT_LOGGIN_TABLE_NAME to show up for this specific table name. I have even hard coded the table name in 'Named Query' and 'CTE' style. BUT no luck. When I run each piece of code alone I get the dataset. there are two fields to join on. Table_Name and ETL data.

For second round I thought it would be space issues. Hence TRIM is also added. BUT still no luck.
Would anyone be able to guide me in general right direction on this. Pick your style of query.

Expected result set is below as well. Sadly, this is going into a VIEW. So I do not think I can use temp tables within the View definition.

```
select  a.Full_Table_Name
,replace(UPPER(Full_Table_Name),'RAW_DB.JA.','' ) as Short_Table_Name
,log.TABLE_NAME as AUDIT_LOGGIN_TABLE_NAME
,a.ROWS_INSERTED
,log.RECORD_COUNT AS AUDIT_LOGGING_RECORD_COUNT
,a.ETL_DATE
, to_date(concat(substring(log.ETL_DATE,0,4),'-',substring(log.ETL_DATE,5,2),'-',substring(log.ETL_DATE,7,2) ) ) as AUDIT_LOGGING_ETL_DATE
,a.START_TIME
,a.END_TIME
,a.DURATION_IN_SECONDS
,a.EXECUTION_STATUS
,case when a.ROWS_INSERTED = log.RECORD_COUNT then 1 else 0 end VALIDATION_RECORD_COUNT_INSERT
from (
select  UPPER(substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12)) as Full_Table_Name
,ROWS_INSERTED
,to_date(START_TIME) as ETL_DATE
,START_TIME
,END_TIME
,datediff(second,START_TIME,END_TIME) as Duration_in_seconds
,EXECUTION_STATUS
from  VW_QUERY_HISTORY as vw
where substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12) like '%JA%'
and QUERY_TYPE = 'COPY'
and UPPER(substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12))  like '%RAW_DB.JA%'
 and to_date(START_TIME) >= dateadd(day,-8,current_date() )
 ) as a
LEFT JOIN SOURCE_TABLE_COUNTS as log  on UPPER(replace(UPPER(log.TABLE_NAME),'MGR.','')) = replace(UPPER(Full_Table_Name),'RAW_DB.JA.','' )
 and 
to_date(a.ETL_DATE) =  to_date(concat(substring(log.ETL_DATE,0,4),'-',substring(log.ETL_DATE,5,2),'-',substring(log.ETL_DATE,7,2) ) )
order by ETL_DATE

///////NAMED QUERY STYLE /////////////////////////////////////////////


select Full_Table_Name
,Short_Table_Name
,AUDIT_LOGGIN_TABLE_NAME
,ROWS_INSERTED
,AUDIT_LOGGING_RECORD_COUNT
,ETL_DATE
,AUDIT_LOGGING_ETL_DATE
,START_TIME
,END_TIME
,DURATION_IN_SECONDS
,case when ROWS_INSERTED = AUDIT_LOGGING_RECORD_COUNT then 1 else 0 end as VALIDATION_RECORD_COUNT_INSERT
from (
  
  select * from (
        select  TRIM(UPPER(substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12))) as Full_Table_Name
        ,TRIM(replace(UPPER(Full_Table_Name),'RAW_DB.JA.','' )) as Short_Table_Name
        ,ROWS_INSERTED
        ,to_date(START_TIME) as ETL_DATE
        ,START_TIME
        ,END_TIME
        ,datediff(second,START_TIME,END_TIME) as Duration_in_seconds
        ,EXECUTION_STATUS
        from  VW_QUERY_HISTORY as vw
        where substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12) like '%JA%'
        and QUERY_TYPE = 'COPY'
        and UPPER(substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12))  like '%RAW_DB.JA%'
         and to_date(START_TIME) >= dateadd(day,-8,current_date() ) 
          ) as sub_qury where  trim(Short_Table_Name) like '%UDT_SKU%'
     ) as a
left join 
( select trim(UPPER(replace(UPPER(log.TABLE_NAME),'MGR.',''))) as AUDIT_LOGGIN_TABLE_NAME
,log.RECORD_COUNT AS AUDIT_LOGGING_RECORD_COUNT
, to_date(concat(substring(log.ETL_DATE,0,4),'-',substring(log.ETL_DATE,5,2),'-',substring(log.ETL_DATE,7,2) ) ) as AUDIT_LOGGING_ETL_DATE
from SOURCE_TABLE_COUNTS as log 
where UPPER(replace(UPPER(log.TABLE_NAME),'MGR.','')) = 'UDT_SKU'
) as audit_log_query
on  trim(a.Short_Table_Name) = trim(audit_log_query.AUDIT_LOGGIN_TABLE_NAME) and 
audit_log_query.AUDIT_LOGGING_ETL_DATE = ETL_DATE

//////////// CTE style

WITH audit_log_query as 
( select trim(UPPER(replace(UPPER(log.TABLE_NAME),'MGR.',''))) as AUDIT_LOGGIN_TABLE_NAME
,log.RECORD_COUNT AS AUDIT_LOGGING_RECORD_COUNT
, to_date(concat(substring(log.ETL_DATE,0,4),'-',substring(log.ETL_DATE,5,2),'-',substring(log.ETL_DATE,7,2) ) ) as AUDIT_LOGGING_ETL_DATE
from SOURCE_TABLE_COUNTS as log 
where UPPER(replace(UPPER(log.TABLE_NAME),'MGR.','')) = 'UDT_SKU'
)

select Full_Table_Name
,Short_Table_Name
,AUDIT_LOGGIN_TABLE_NAME
,ROWS_INSERTED
,AUDIT_LOGGING_RECORD_COUNT
,ETL_DATE
,AUDIT_LOGGING_ETL_DATE
,START_TIME
,END_TIME
,DURATION_IN_SECONDS
,case when ROWS_INSERTED = AUDIT_LOGGING_RECORD_COUNT then 1 else 0 end as VALIDATION_RECORD_COUNT_INSERT
from (
  
  select * from (
        select  TRIM(UPPER(substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12))) as Full_Table_Name
        ,TRIM(replace(UPPER(Full_Table_Name),'RAW_DB.JA.','' )) as Short_Table_Name
        ,ROWS_INSERTED
        ,to_date(START_TIME) as ETL_DATE
        ,START_TIME
        ,END_TIME
        ,datediff(second,START_TIME,END_TIME) as Duration_in_seconds
        ,EXECUTION_STATUS
        from  VW_QUERY_HISTORY as vw
        where substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12) like '%JA%'
        and QUERY_TYPE = 'COPY'
        and UPPER(substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12))  like '%RAW_DB.JA%'
         and to_date(START_TIME) >= dateadd(day,-8,current_date() ) 
          ) as sub_qury where  trim(Short_Table_Name) like '%UDT_SKU%'
     ) as a
left join audit_log_query on  trim(a.Short_Table_Name) = trim(audit_log_query.AUDIT_LOGGIN_TABLE_NAME) 
 and  audit_log_query.AUDIT_LOGGING_ETL_DATE = ETL_DATE
```

Expected DATA

```
FULL_TABLE_NAME|SHORT_TABLE_NAME|AUDIT_LOGGIN_TABLE_NAME|ROWS_INSERTED|AUDIT_LOGGING_RECORD_COUNT|ETL_DATE|AUDIT_LOGGING_ETL_DATE|START_TIME|END_TIME|DURATION_IN_SECONDS|VALIDATION_RECORD_COUNT_INSERT
RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU|UDT_SKU||19697||2021-04-01||2021-04-01 07:59:39.101 -0700|2021-04-01 07:59:40.048 -0700|1|0
RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU|UDT_SKU||27144||2021-04-05||2021-04-05 08:03:37.907 -0700|2021-04-05 08:03:39.377 -0700|2|0
RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU|UDT_SKU||16536||2021-03-31||2021-03-31 08:03:05.626 -0700|2021-03-31 08:03:06.921 -0700|1|0
RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU|UDT_SKU||19182||2021-04-02||2021-04-02 08:03:33.296 -0700|2021-04-02 08:03:34.803 -0700|1|0
RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU|UDT_SKU||885||2021-04-03||2021-04-03 08:04:15.123 -0700|2021-04-03 08:04:16.071 -0700|1|0
RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU|UDT_SKU||0||2021-04-04||2021-04-04 07:30:23.213 -0700|2021-04-04 07:30:23.862 -0700|0|0
RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU|UDT_SKU||1262||2021-04-04||2021-04-04 17:35:01.110 -0700|2021-04-04 17:35:02.500 -0700|1|0
RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU|UDT_SKU||197899||2021-04-06||2021-04-06 08:00:56.860 -0700|2021-04-06 08:00:59.798 -0700|3|0
RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU|UDT_SKU||107433||2021-03-30||2021-03-30 08:02:34.231 -0700|2021-03-30 08:02:36.846 -0700|2|0
RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU|UDT_SKU||17794||2021-04-07||2021-04-07 08:00:40.782 -0700|2021-04-07 08:00:41.590 -0700|1|0
```

Comment: Co-worker was able to figure out the issue . Solution : replace(TRIM(replace(UPPER(Full_Table_Name),'RAW_TABLE_DB.JDA.','' )), char(13), '') as Short_Table_Name .

Comment: Ya, just had worked out that your output was expect JDA but your replace was 'RAW_DB.JA.'

Answer (score 1):

So as you noted the tables schema are `JDA` not `JA` so your filters need to be changed.

there are a number of places you select to output you want and then reapply the same logic in the WHERE clauses, but slightly different, you can just use the aliased SELECT columns in your WHERE.

Also your date parsing can just use the formatted verse and save of the string splicing.

```
 TO_DATE(log.etl_date, 'YYYYMMDD') AS audit_logging_etl_date
```

also it's nice you show input data, as trying to guess the audit format was rather painful.

```
WITH source_table_counts AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        ('mgr.UDT_SKU',123, '20210401')
        v(table_name, record_count, etl_date)
), vw_query_history AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        ('0123456789 RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU from',19697,'2021-04-01 07:59:39.101 -0700','2021-04-01 07:59:40.048 -0700',NULL,'COPY'),
        ('0123456789 RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU from',27144,'2021-04-05 08:03:37.907 -0700','2021-04-05 08:03:39.377 -0700',NULL,'COPY'),
        ('0123456789 RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU from',16536,'2021-03-31 08:03:05.626 -0700','2021-03-31 08:03:06.921 -0700',NULL,'COPY'),
        ('0123456789 RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU from',19182,'2021-04-02 08:03:33.296 -0700','2021-04-02 08:03:34.803 -0700',NULL,'COPY'),
        ('01234567891RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU from',885,'2021-04-03 08:04:15.123 -0700','2021-04-03 08:04:16.071 -0700',NULL,'COPY'),
        ('01234567891RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU from',0,'2021-04-04 07:30:23.213 -0700','2021-04-04 07:30:23.862 -0700',NULL,'COPY'),
        ('01234567891RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU from',1262,'2021-04-04 17:35:01.110 -0700','2021-04-04 17:35:02.500 -0700',NULL,'COPY'),
        ('01234567891RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU from',197899,'2021-04-06 08:00:56.860 -0700','2021-04-06 08:00:59.798 -0700',NULL,'COPY'),
        ('01234567891RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU from',107433,'2021-03-30 08:02:34.231 -0700','2021-03-30 08:02:36.846 -0700',NULL,'COPY'),
        ('01234567891RAW_DB.JDA.UDT_SKU from',17794,'2021-04-07 08:00:40.782 -0700','2021-04-07 08:00:41.590 -0700',NULL,'COPY')
        v(query_text, rows_inserted, start_time, end_time, execution_status,query_type)
)

, audit_log_query AS ( 
    select 
        TRIM(REPLACE(UPPER(log.table_name),'MGR.','')) AS audit_loggin_table_name
        ,log.record_count AS audit_logging_record_count
        ,TO_DATE(log.etl_date, 'YYYYMMDD') AS audit_logging_etl_date
        --,TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(log.etl_date,0,4),'-',SUBSTRING(log.etl_date,5,2),'-', SUBSTRING(log.etl_date,7,2) ) ) AS audit_logging_etl_date   
    FROM source_table_counts AS log 
    WHERE audit_loggin_table_name = 'UDT_SKU'
)
SELECT 
    a.full_table_name
    ,a.short_table_name
    ,al.audit_loggin_table_name
    ,a.rows_inserted
    ,al.audit_logging_record_count
    ,a.etl_date
    ,al.audit_logging_etl_date
    ,a.start_time
    ,a.end_time
    ,a.duration_in_seconds
    ,IFF(a.rows_inserted = al.audit_logging_record_count, 1, 0) AS validation_record_count_insert
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT  
            TRIM(UPPER(SUBSTRING(query_text, 11, CHARINDEX('from', query_text)-12))) AS full_table_name
            ,REPLACE(full_table_name,'RAW_DB.JDA.','' ) AS short_table_name
            ,rows_inserted
            ,TO_DATE(start_time) AS etl_date
            ,start_time
            ,end_time
            ,DATEDIFF('second', start_time, end_time) AS duration_in_seconds
            ,execution_status
        FROM  vw_query_history AS vw
        WHERE full_table_name like '%JDA%'
            AND query_type = 'COPY'
            AND full_table_name  like '%RAW_DB.JDA%'
             AND to_date(START_TIME) >= dateadd(day,-8,current_date() ) 
    ) as sub_qury 
    where short_table_name like '%UDT_SKU%'
) as a
LEFT JOIN audit_log_query AS al
    on a.short_table_name = al.audit_loggin_table_name
        and al.audit_logging_etl_date = a.etl_date;
```